# How to get subpages of an URL without knowing them?

Tags: url, scrapy, web-crawler

I'd like to know any Subpages of a certain URL. E.g. I have the URL example.com. There might exist the subpages example.com/home, example.com/help and so on. Is it possible to get all of such subpages without knowing there exact name?

I thought I can handle this problem with a web crawler. But it just crawls for pages mentioned on the page itself.

I hope you understand my problem and can help me with it.

Thank you!

Comment: you can guess names or use list of popular names. You can generate all possible names (brute force). You could ask Google Search - maybe it has other subpages in its database. So normally you can't do it.

Comment: I will send you the code later when I am back at home.

1. The problem is that the Subpage I need is just generated randomly without any pattern with about 30 characters. So guessing the subpages would take ages.

2. The subpages are not indexed, so I cannot find them just with Google's help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes. Scrapy "crawl" spiders work by setting rules that can be set to do exactly what you're trying to. When in doubt, always [go to the docs!](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)

Couple things to note:
  You can create a crawl spider the same way when creating the generic spider!

```
scrapy genspider -t crawl nameOfSpider website.com
```

With a crawl spider, you then have to set rules to basically tell scrapy where and where not to go; how's your regex?!

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com'] # PART 1: Domain Restriction
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*')), callback='parse_item'), # PART 2: Call Back
    )
```

Now I copied and pasted this from the Official docs, and changed up what it should look like for you but I havent checked the code so yeah... teh logic is there though..

IThis works by getting ALL the link that it can see depending on the rules you set, does something with said link.

1. You want to restrict all other domains but the one your scrapinng
2. In the example I set the wildcard to literally accept every and any page in the domain... once you figure out tehs tructure of a website, you can use logic to build out what you need.

You should take a look at the docs more often though. I have been using scrapy for about 6-7 years and I still find myself going back to the man pages!

Comment: The OP asks for a way to find URLs that cannot be found crawling.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t.

The way you describe the situation, the website intends those desired URLs to be secret.

Any way to find such URLs would be a security exploit that should be reported to the website owners right away so they can fix it.